# Latitude, Longitude to 3D point in three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I want to find a function that is the inverse of the azimuth/inclination of three.js's PolyhedronGeometry calculations; that is, given an azimuth and inclination value, find the 3D point at that angle from origin.

Is there already a function like that in three.js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Besides *azimuth* and *elevation*, you also need *distance*, to locate the 3D point (else you only have a line/direction).

Assuming you know `R`, the distance of the point from the origin, `θ` (the azimuth) and `ϕ` (the elevation), you can get the 3D coordinates as follows:

```
x = R*cos(ϕ)*sin(θ)
y = R*cos(ϕ)*cos(θ)
z = R*sin(ϕ)
```

Hope that helps.